# Grouping together booktile and series in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex-chicago for my references. My bib file includes many references to conference papers that I have imported from the ACM digital library. The abbreviations to these conferences are often better know than the full titles of the conferences themselves. So for `inproceedings` entries, I have included the abbreviation using the `series` field. I would like to group the `booktitle` and `series` fields together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    authordate,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex-chicago} % biblatex setup

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{paper2012,
    author = {Smith, John},
date = {2012},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
    series = {CHI '12},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},    
    publisher = {{ACM}},    
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This example currently outputs the following:

Smith, John. 2012. “Paper Title” In *Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems*, 937–946. CHI ’12. New York, NY, USA: ACM.

instead I would like to change the output of `inproceedings` entries, so that `booktitle` and  `series` fields are grouped together like this:

Smith, John. 2012. “Paper Title” In *Proceedings of the 2012 ACM Annual Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems — CHI ’12*, 937–46. New York, NY, USA: ACM.

an important caveat being, that not all `inproceedings` entries have a `series` field.

is this possible with biblatex-chicago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other solutions suggested to used `booktitleaddon` instead of `series`.  Personally I don't think that `series` is the right field to use. Consider for example Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science series, publishing proceedings of computer science conference. Each book has its title (which often is different from the conference title), but the proceedings are know by the conference name of more often by they acronym. And then it is customary to include a reference to the LNCS series and the number in the series.

Biblatex, when used with `biber`, offers the p possibility to create a new field. I suggest to add the `acronym` field.

This can be done with

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{acronym}
\end{filecontents}
```

It creates a local biblatex configuration file.

Then we have to give the instructions on how to typeset the new field (in italics for `in proceedings`)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{acronym}{\textit{#1}}
```

The final step is to modify the appropriate `bibmacro`, in this case `btitle+bstitle`.

```
\newbibmacro*{btitle+bstitle}{% 
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
  {}
  {\ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{audio}\OR\ifentrytype{music}\OR%
      \ifentrytype{video}}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cms-in:}}%
    \printtext{%
      \printfield{booktitle}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
      \printfield[booktitle]{booksubtitle}}%
      \setunit{\addspace---\addspace}%
      \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
        {\printfield{acronym}}
        {}%
    \newcunit
    \printfield{booktitleaddon}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}}}
```

Notice we use `\ifentrytype{inproceedings}` to localise the change only to this entry type.

Here is the full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    authordate,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex-chicago} % biblatex setup

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{paper201x,
    author = {Smith, John},
date = {2012},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Long Title of the Confererence},
    acronym = {CONF'2012},
    pages = {937-946},
    series = {LNCS},
    number = {1234},
    location = {Heidelberg},    
    publisher = {Springer},    
}

@inproceedings{paper2012a,
    author = {Smith, John},
date = {2012},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
    series = {CHI '12},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},    
    publisher = {{ACM}},    
}

@inproceedings{paper2012b,
    author = {Smith, John},
date = {2012},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
    acronym = {CHI '12},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},    
    publisher = {{ACM}},    
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{acronym}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{acronym}{\textit{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{btitle+bstitle}{% InIn fix from N&B
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
  {}
  {\ifthenelse{\ifentrytype{audio}\OR\ifentrytype{music}\OR%
      \ifentrytype{video}}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{cms-in:}}%
    \printtext{%
      \printfield{booktitle}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
      \printfield[booktitle]{booksubtitle}}%
      \setunit{\addspace---\addspace}%
      \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
        {\printfield{acronym}}
        {}%
    \newcunit
    \printfield{booktitleaddon}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}}}



\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to use the `booktitleaddon` field instead, since it is already designed to be printed at the location you want.  However, these sorts of fields are usually pretty 'deep' in the driver, so you need to be careful to make sure your changes only affect `inproceedings` entries since it uses the same bibmacros as other "in-

I would do it like this: create new bibmacros and use the `xpatch` package to replace what's needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    authordate,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex-chicago} % biblatex setup

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\diff}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}% <-- just to highlight differences

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}% we need more entries...
@inproceedings{paper2012,
    author = {Smith, John},
    date = {2012},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
    booktitleaddon = {\diff{CHI '12}},
    number = 33,
    series = {\diff{This is the series}},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},
    publisher = {{ACM}},
}

@inproceedings{paper2013,
    author = {Smith, John},
    date = {2013},
    title = {Different Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
    booksubtitle = {\diff{With a Subtitle}},
    booktitleaddon = {CHI '12},
    number = 34,
    series = {\diff{This is the series}},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},
    publisher = {{ACM}},
}

@inproceedings{paper2011,
    author = {Smith, John},
    date = {2011},
    title = {Another Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
    booksubtitle = {\diff{With a Subtitle \& No Booktitleaddon}},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},
    publisher = {{ACM}},
}

@incollection{paper2014,
    author = {Doe, Jane},
    date = {2014},
    title = {Jane's Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Collected Essays},
    booksubtitle = {\diff{With a Series and a Booktitleaddon}},
    series = {CHI '13},
    booktitleaddon = {\diff{This is the booktitleaddon (which is preceded by the normal comma)}},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},
    publisher = {{ACM}},
}

\end{filecontents*}

% we need our own bibmacros
\newbibmacro*{INP-btitle+bstitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \printfield{booktitle}%
       \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
       \printfield[booktitle]{booksubtitle}}%
     \newcunit
     \setunit{\addspace ---\addspace}%
     \printfield{booktitleaddon}}}

\newbibmacro*{INP-mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{INP-btitle+bstitle}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
  {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}% Fix customc?
  {\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
  {}
  {\iffieldundef{volume}
    {\printtext{%
        \printfield{maintitle}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
      \printfield[maintitle]{mainsubtitle}}%
    \newcunit
    \printfield{maintitleaddon}}
  {\printfield{volume}%
    \printfield{part}%
    \setunit{\addspace}
    \bibstring{ofseries}%
    \setunit{\addspace}
    \printtext{%
      \printfield{maintitle}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
      \printfield[maintitle]{mainsubtitle}}%
    \newcunit
    \printfield{maintitleaddon}}}}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% this puts the booktitleaddon field in 'italics' only for @inproceedings entry types
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{booktitleaddon}{\emph{#1}}
% this replaces a portion of the default inproceedings bibdriver with the macrs we defined above.
\xpatchbibmacro{inproceedings}{mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}{INP-mtitle+mstitle+vol+part+btitle+bstitle}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

... And, as I was writing this, I see moewe posted a different solution.  Part of it could be combined here so that you don't need to rewrite your bib entries.  However, I still think mapping to `booktitleaddon` is the better field to use by default, if only because books are far more likely to have a subtitle than bibliographical information that needs to be put in the `titleaddon` field.

Comment: (... This wasn't meant to be community wiki.  Somehow I accidentally tick that box far to often...)

Answer (score 2):

I think the position for the short title (your `series` field) is that of `booksubtitle`, so what we can do is the following:

We just change the `series` field for `@inproccedings` to `booksubtitle`. This of course only works if there is no entry that actually has a proper `series` entry, also `booksubtitle` needs to be empty.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
        \step[fieldsource=series, fieldtarget=booksubtitle]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{proceedings}
        \step[fieldsource=series, fieldtarget=subtitle]
    }
  }
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    authordate,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex-chicago} % biblatex setup
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{paper2012,
    author = {Smith, John},
date = {2012},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 2012 ACM annual conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems},
    series = {CHI '12},
    pages = {937-946},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},    
    publisher = {{ACM}},    
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{inproceedings}
        \step[fieldsource=series, fieldtarget=booksubtitle]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{proceedings}
        \step[fieldsource=series, fieldtarget=subtitle]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]